# $where mongo operator work around in meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a MongoDB query that works perfectly in MongoDB shell

```js
 db.collection.find({ $where: 
function(){
    var num = this.numbers;
    function isInList(numbers,matchArray) 
        {
            var reducedNums = numbers.filter(function(num) {
            return matchArray.indexOf(num) !== -1
            });
            if (reducedNums.length == 7){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return isInList(num, [ 28 ,5, 17, 47, 1, 24, 37, 19, 4, 3 ] );
    }
}
);
```

How can I implement this in MeteorJS what is the work around?

Explanations as per request: 
I need a function in the serverside, does not matter if it works in the client side.
The function has to match the given array with the numbers field on the document and tell me how many numbers in the array are matching and the document ID or something like this :

```js
if (match.length == 7){
                return "DOCUMENT";
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

Tried this:
Added the code in (meteor is server):

```js
console.log(Tickets.find({ $where: 
function(){
        var num = this.numbers;
        function isInList(numbers,matchArray) 
            {
                var reducedNums = numbers.filter(function(num) {
                return matchArray.indexOf(num) !== -1
                });
                if (reducedNums.length == 7){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return isInList(num, [ 28 ,5, 17, 47, 1, 24, 37, 19, 4, 3 ] );
        }
    }
))
```

output was like this:

```js
 I20140623-17:15:02.690(2)? { _mongo:
 I20140623-17:15:02.910(2)?    { _connectCallbacks: [ [Function] ],
 I20140623-17:15:02.911(2)?      _observeMultiplexers: {},
 I20140623-17:15:02.912(2)?      _onFailoverHook: { nextCallbackId: 0, callbacks: {} },
 I20140623-17:15:02.913(2)?      _docFetcher: { _mongoConnection: [Circular], _callbacksForCacheKey: {} },
 I20140623-17:15:02.914(2)?      _oplogHandle:
 ...
 ...
 ...
 I20140623-17:15:03.025(2)?      selector: { '$where': [Function] },
 I20140623-17:15:03.027(2)?      options: { transform: null } },
 I20140623-17:15:03.030(2)?   _synchronousCursor: null }
 => Meteor server restarted
```

When I do .fetch() all the documents will print out which should not happen this code works perfectly in mondodb shell.

**Solution** thank's to @AndrewMao:
1st solution:
By adding the .toString() in the end of the function the .toString() as I tested works perfectly in NodeJS

ex:

```js
Tickets.find({'$where':     function(){
    var num = this.numbers;
    function isInList(numbers,matchArray) 
        {
            var reducedNums = numbers.filter(function(num) {
            return matchArray.indexOf(num) !== -1
            });
            if (reducedNums.length == 7){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return isInList(num, [ 28 ,5, 17, 47, 1, 24, 37, 19, 4, 3 ] );
    }.toString();
}).fetch();
```

2nd solution: This is if you want to add you custom array or something else in the query:

You have to pass your function as a string in one line, also you can add other string in it as I did with the random array. Look at the function call (isInList(num,['+ random +']);}') in the example below.

ex:

```js
 var random = [ 19 ,3, 14, 24, 2, 38, 48, 19, 4, 3 ];

 Tickets.find({'$where': 'function(){var num = this.numbers; function isInList(numbers,matchArray) {var reducedNums = numbers.filter(function(num) { return matchArray.indexOf(num) !== -1  }); if (reducedNums.length == 7){ return true;} else {  return false;   }}return isInList(num,['+ random +']);}'}).fetch();
```

Comment: Ask yourself if it really does need to be this complicated. You need to eliminate the function. Maybe also specify in the question what it is you need this construction for.

Comment: @marcodejongh I think the intent is pretty clear. This is a "lotto" draw evaluation, as in 7 numbers matching from a given set. There are a few ways to process this, just that all of them are out of scope of "minimongo". For which I wish that meteor users would understand the limitations of the client side implementation and simply just go for server side code. Whole collection side matching makes no sense on the client.

Comment: @NeilLunn How would you do this serverside then? As far as I know the serverside find in meteor accepts the same selectors as the client mini mongo variation. So you still wont be able to use a function. The only way I could think of is manually connecting to meteor with the npm module.

Comment: @MarcodeJongh I edited the question added explanation as per your request.

Comment: Is your code failing? By convention in Meteor you will begin by defining a collection, which can be server-side only, e.g. Numbers = new Meteor.Collection('numbers').  Then a server-side Numbers.find() in your Meteor code would correspond to db.numbers.find() in the mongo shell. From there you can diagnose if the $where is failing or not.

Comment: As @NeilLunn mentioned this is somthing like lottos logic even though it is not i have a document that conatins a numbers field with an array of numbers and I have another array with numbers I want to match how many numbers from that array are in the given array. The function works perfectly in mongodb shell. If it works serverside then is perfect that's all I need it to work in server side the client side only needs the _ids of the documents. I'm new in meteor and in all the nodejs idea. What is the work around and how can I do it !?

Comment: @JeremyS. I added the output i get when i trie to console.log() the find function.

Comment: What happens if you log Tickets.find({/*. . .*/}).fetch()?

Comment: All the documents in the collection are printing out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is probably not with the `$where` query; it's because you are printing out a cursor rather than the matched documents. Namely, append `.fetch()` to the end of the `.find()`: http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch

A cursor is a reference to a selected group of documents and does not actually grab the documents until you try to `.map()`, `.fetch()`, or `.forEach()` on it.

Additionally, you need to pass the `$where` function as a string, not as an actual function: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/ErgCC4g_bB0. This is needed for Mongo to process and run the function (it is not being done in Node.)

```
Tickets.find({ $where: 'function() { ... }' });
```

You won't be able to have the benefit of source code highlighting, but the function you tested should work. You can also try

```
Tickets.find({ $where: function() { ... }.toString() });
```

but this may only work in browsers and not in Node.

Comment: When I do .fetch() all the documents in the collection are printing out.

Comment: That's because you have it in a `console.log()` block. What did you expect to happen? Meteor's collection API is *not* an exact copy of the MongoDB shell commands, and you should not expect it to have the same syntax.

Comment: I expect it will work like in mondodb shell, that will print out only the documents that match

Comment: Yes that's why i stated in the title what is the work around !!

Comment: Pass in the function as a string. See my update in the answer.

Comment: Used it like this. Collection.find({'$where': function(){...}}). The problem is it prints out every document in the collection.

Comment: Again, wrap the function part in a string, so it says `'function() { ... }'`. The function is being run in Mongo, and not in Node, and it won't be serialized properly - see the link.

Comment: @user1898399 you need to write the function in a string, not in bare Javascript. I don't know how else to explain this.

Comment: O Lord thank you :) you just solved many other issues for me with this. Can I ask you one more thing how can I pass an outside matching array

Comment: Like if a have a variable with an array arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] how can I add this in the function ?

Comment: No i have arrays with mixed numbers the string will be a strict match. If you have any good idea just leave a comment pls... I think I will manage that, i must now be away. But with this answer you just made my day :) thank you allot