# Filter subscription bases on user roles in Meteor

Tags: meteor, filter, roles

I am using [meteor-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) package for adding roles functionality to the app. Now I'm trying to filter a subscription of product based on the user of having a role to see that product category.

I thought I can use [mongo $where in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364886/where-mongo-operator-work-around-in-meteorjs) but I can specify the $where function only as serialized string which does not have access to the roles package.

Example of adding a user to a role for viewing specific category.

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(userIdA, 'view-product-category', 'product-category-a');
```

Current code that does not work. `userId` does not exists when the function get deserialized in mongo engine.

```
Meteor.publish('products', function () {
  let userId = this.userId;

  let query = {
    $where: function () {
      return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'view-product-category', `product-catogory-${this.category}`);
    }.toString();
  };

  return Products.find(query);
});
```

How does one filter a collection based on values different collection, which what I'm trying to do here ?

Current direction is to serialize the function myself and put the values needed there. I'm looking to know if there is more general and robust way of doing this kind of acl access filtering on subscriptions.

Comment: Why dont you show some code? That makes it always easier to help.

Comment: I think this is a scoping issue, though I have not tried it myself. Have you tried `var userId = this.userId`?

Comment: As said, userId does not exists. And it does not matter `var` or `let`. Tried them both. Scope does not maintained when serializing a function to string and afterward mongo deserialize it and execute it with `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$where` is unindexed and slow. I believe what you're trying to do is filter products that have a category key. The user has a number of roles that allow them to view various categories.

You want to setup your query as:

```
Products.find({category: {$in: userCategories}});
```

Fortunately, the [roles api](http://alanning.github.io/meteor-roles/classes/Roles.html) has a `getRolesForUser` function that will get all the user's roles for you.

So do:

```
const myRoles = getRolesForUser(Meteor.userId());
const userCategories = f(myRoles); // whatever you need to do to format these roles as categories
Products.find({category: {$in: userCategories}});
```

I'm not clear on how your role *groups* play into this hence the pseudo-answer. But basically you want `userCategories` to be an *array* of the category names the user has access to. This query will be fast as long as the `category` field is indexed.

Comment: Yes, that's is currently the option I am using. Putting the `role permission` on the collection items themselves. Is that recommended for granular permission like viewing/editing item also ?

Comment: That feels like a bit of overkill but I don't know what your business rules are. I try to ensure CRUD permissions are abstracted out into a small set of core roles and then use record ownership or "membership" to control document-level permissions. Incidentally, did this approach work for you?

Comment: Yes, I've added permissions on each item in the collection. That was needed because each item could be edited and viewed by different people. I could have gone and implemented group permissions. but in that case, the groups would corresponde 1-to-1 to the items in the collection.

Comment: If the approach worked then you should accept the answer or are you still stuck with the `$where` operator?